# clrscr() в Xcode

Tags: xcode

Есть ли какая альтернатива функции clrscr() для Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>
void clear_screen()
{
  DWORD n;                         /* Number of characters written */
  DWORD size;                      /* number of visible characters */
  COORD coord = {0};               /* Top left screen position */
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  /* Get a handle to the console */
  HANDLE h = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );
  /* Find the number of characters to overwrite */
  size = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
  /* Overwrite the screen buffer with whitespace */
  FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( h, TEXT ( ' ' ), size, coord, &n );
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );
  FillConsoleOutputAttribute ( h, csbi.wAttributes, size, coord, &n );
  /* Reset the cursor to the top left position */
  SetConsoleCursorPosition ( h, coord );
}
```